# Classes and list

Tags: c#, list, class

So, say I have something like the following:

```
 public class CProperty : CTitledEntity
    {
        private int numberOfNodes;
        private int elementType;

        public CProperty(int id, string title, int numberOfNodes, int elementType, string descripton = "")
            : base(id, title, descripton)
        {
            this.numberOfNodes = numberOfNodes;
            this.elementType = elementType;
        }

        public string Property
        {
            get
            {
                CElement.ElementTypes enumDisplayStatus = ((CElement.ElementTypes)numberOfNodes);
                string stringValue = enumDisplayStatus.ToString();
                return stringValue + elementType;
            }
        }
    }
```

and

```
 public CElement(int id, int numberOfNodes, int index, int[] nodes)
            : base(id)
        {
            this.NumberOfNodes = numberOfNodes;
            this.Nodes = new int[numberOfNodes];
            this.Index = index;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++)
                this.Nodes[i] = nodes[i];
        }
        public int NumberOfNodes { get; set; }
        public int[] Nodes { get; set; }
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public CProperty Property { get; set; }
```

and I have a list of these:

```
CEntityCollection<CProperty> properties = ReadProperty();
CEntityCollection<CElement> elements = ReadElement();
```

First of all,I'm so sorry for my bad English.
I have to create constructor in CElement class with CPropety param.CProperty param I give from **properties**.And I have no idea what to do it.

Comment: do you want to say that you want to pass CProperty object in CElement class constructor?

Comment: Side note: the "C" prefix for classes is not generally used in C# ..

Comment: What do you mean with: "CProperty param I give from properties"?

Comment: One of parametres in CElement constructor must be CProperty class piece

Comment: So it has no reference to the **properties** in `CEntityCollection<CProperty> properties = ReadProperty();`. If this is the case it is as simple as Faisal's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just add CProperty obje in your CElemenet class and add this to parameter of the constructor.

```
public CElement(int id, int numberOfNodes, int index, int[] nodes, CProperty property) : base(id)
    : base(id)
{
    this.NumberOfNodes = numberOfNodes;
    this.Nodes = new int[numberOfNodes];
    this.Index = index;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; i++)
        this.Nodes[i] = nodes[i];
    Property = property;
}

public CProperty Property { get; set; }
public int NumberOfNodes { get; set; }
public int[] Nodes { get; set; }
public int Index { get; set; }
public CProperty Property { get; set; }
```

Comment: if you want to add multiple properties then you can have a list of CProperty in CElement.